# What does /sbin/ifconfig contain?

Tags: ifconfig

[image]

My file shows as attached.
Is it corrupted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, things in `/sbin/` are binary (non-text), executable files. This, in particular, is an x86_64 ELF executable (try `file /sbin/ifconfig`). Out of curiosity, what did you expect to see?

Comment: Thanks, instead of running it as command /etc/ifconfig, i did vi /etc/ifconfig

Answer (score 1):

It's a binary file. You can't simply `cat` or see the content of it.

It contains instructions sent to the OS.

I can't tell if that's the exact output I'd expect, but it looks like the output of a binary file. If you provide the. Sesión and hash of it, I could try and see if it matches an unmodified binary.

What are you trying to figure out?